# Error while Loading a Pyspark dataframe into a table in postgres RDS

Tags: dataframe, jdbc, pyspark, load, amazon-rds

Getting the following error while trying to write a dataframe into a postgres table in RDS

**Write DataFrame to active_user table in RDS**

```
clean_user_df.write.jdbc(url=jdbc_url, table='active_user', mode=mode, properties=config)
```

[image: screenshot displaying error]

Comment: It seems that you don't have the jdbc driver or not loaded.

Comment: Is this the line of code the jdbc driver?
!wget https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-42.2.16.jar

Comment: How are you creating your connection properties and setting the driver inside those connection properties which you are passing as config?

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the JDBC driver (you can use the one in your comment), then follow the [official instruction](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html) to use that jar file

```
./bin/spark-shell --driver-class-path postgresql-9.4.1207.jar --jars postgresql-9.4.1207.jar
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. The actual problem was with the configuration settings for RDS. When I fixed that, my code worked.